# need headphones for kids

Tags: headphones

I need to get really tough over the ear headphones for my pre teen kids. I am not interested in Beats and want something that is over the ear and that will last. High bass is not a priority. They are strictly for listening and don't require a mike.

Answer (score 2):

For a recent vacation, involving multiple connecting flights, rental cars, hotel rooms and hiking, I bought the relatively cheap [JLab JBuddies headphones](http://www.walmart.com/ip/JLab-JBuddies-Folding-Headphones/41136487) for my children for less than $20 each.

[image: JLabs Headphone]

A couple notes:

- The over the ear component is small. It definitely wouldn't feel comfortable on my ears. I'm not sure about pre-teen, but for young elementary school it works great.
- They fold up and are compact, which was great for traveling and storage
- They have a standard mini-jack and work great on the tablets
- Built in maximum volume limiter
- These survived being stuffed in backpacks by less than careful children, tossed around various hotel rooms, cars and airplane storage locations. The cords were not gently wrapped up after each usage and generally treated as I'd expect younger children to treat electronics when I don't glare at them to not break something. They survived all of that.